# C# WinForms: Multicolumn ListBox with Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, vertical-scrolling, multiple-columns

I need to display data in a way similar to the central panel shown here: http://www.binaryworks.it/extremegamesmanager/images/features/features_2.PNG (with game covers and titles).

I already have a similar control (based on the standard WinForms ListBox), but it has a horizontal scroll (since ListBox doesn't allow for multicolumn verical scrolling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn.aspx)

ListView doesn't seem to support custom objects as elements, and DataGrid is good for rows of related data - yet I have a list of images (with captions).

How do you recommend I proceed - is there a quicker (easier) solution than extending a Panel?

Comment: Have a look at this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13006/Extended-ListView

Comment: @AppDeveloper I don't think that will do, since the Extended ListView supports rows of related data - all I have is a List<> with separate objects (image + text). I don't want headers, but a flow of objects that is broken into lines (like text).

Comment: i hav done something similar, will help you out when back from class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 3rd party component, but you may check out [Better Thumbnail Browser](http://www.componentowl.com/better-thumbnail-browser) which is like ListView, but supports Thumbnails view allowing arbitrary image sizes, background thumbnail loading and the items can be centered or left-aligned, but their internal spacing does not change as in ListView's LargeIcon view:

[image]

We offer a freeware component [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) that supports LargeIcon view with arbitrary image sizes.

Both controls have great many options for layout and display.